# C++ Header file - syntax problems

Tags: c++, file, syntax, header

I have some errors in my header file, which I don't know how to fix because I am fairly new to C++.

Here is the code of the header file:

```
#pragma once

typedef unsigned int uint;

class DCEncryption
{
public:
    static char* manageData(char*, char*, uint);

private:
    static int max(int, int);
    static uint leftRotate(uint, int);
};
```

And here are the errors:

```
 - dcencryption.h(12): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
 - dcencryption.h(12): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
 - dcencryption.h(12): error C2760: syntax error : expected '{' not ';'
 - dcencryption.h(13): error C2144: syntax error : 'uint' should be preceded by '}'
 - dcencryption.h(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
 - dcencryption.h(13): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
 - dcencryption.h(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
 - dcencryption.h(13): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: I believe on some compilers, `uint` is a reserved keyword for `unsigned int`. I may be wrong, but try changing your naming scheme.

Comment: @Drise - that does not sound very likely, unless what you remember was in fact C#.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Regardless, it seems to be some sort of macro or `#define` conflict. I still blame a naming conflict.

Comment: @Drise - it surely is, but with `max` rather than with `uint`, and it is definitely never a "reserved keyword", but just a macro.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Thank you for correcting my nomenclature error. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @Drise, how would that explain the errors on line 12, which doesn't mention uint?

Comment: @JonathanWakely You have a point, true, and although I wasn't accurately correct, I was in the general ballpark "naming conflict".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably on Windows and you have included `windef.h` directly or indirectly (through `windows.h`, maybe) from your main `.cpp` file before including the shown file.

It so happens that `max` is a macro defined in `windef.h` that does not expand nicely in your context.

This can quite easily happen on some other platforms as well.

Comment: If it indeed is a problem with the `max` macro in WinDef.h, you can turn it (and the `min` macro) off by defining `NOMINMAX`, either project wide or before including any Windows headers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the method's name and all 8 errors were gone. Thanks again.